# JavaEE - WAR - Deployed :: How to read a file from resource directory

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish, war

I believe the "correct" way one is supposed to do this is `getResourceAsStream()` but it just doesn't seem to cut it.

My situation:

I have a web application in Java that will be eventually deployed to a few different web servers the possibilities are **GlassFish**, **Tomcat**, and **WildFly**.  Currently I'm working on a mac with Netbeans and I have access to **WildFly** and **GlassFish**.  The project is mavenized

What I need to do is read and write two different Excel files.  One serves as a "template" and one serves as the output file.  The application previously ran standalone and I'm trying to wrap it into a JSF web site.

I need to obtain an `FileInputStream` for my one of the methods and eventually create an output file which will be served back to the user via http.

From what I gather the appropriate way to do this is supposed to be:

**XLSX File**

```
/src/main/resources/ANALYSIS_template.xlsx
```

**Location once compiled into WAR file :: WildFly**

```
/usr/local/opt/wildfly-as/libexec/standalone/deployments/fleetForecast-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/ANALYSIS_template.xlsx
```

**Location once compiled into WAR file :: GlassFish**

```
~/devel/fleetforecast/target/fleetForecast-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/ANALYSIS_template.xlsx
```

**Java Code**

I think I've maybe managed to get an input stream to the file with the command:

```
InputStream is1 = getClass().getResourceAsStream("ANALYSIS_template.xlsx");
```

I've also tried `("/ANALYSIS_template.xlsx")` by the way which behaves similarly.  When I try to read from this input stream

```
try {
        is1.read();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FleetBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mitre.fleetforecast.bean.FleetBean.<init>(FleetBean.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
    ... 76 more
```

Any assistance offered or thought of would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You definitely do not want to use absolute paths or paths containing things like `/usr/local` or `src/main`... Check out [this](http://www.jugsardegna.org/vqwiki/jsp/Wiki?LoadResourcesOnJ2EEWebApplications).

Comment: My java code is not using absolute paths -> i was just pointing out where they are on the filesystem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end it looks like this is the code that did the trick.  I have NO idea why but apparently it worked and I'm not complaining.

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader()
                         .getResourceAsStream("/ANALYSIS_template.xlsx");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

I made a new project form scratch and this code worked.  Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this :

```
InputStream is1 = URLClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("/classes/ANALYSIS_template.xlsx");
```

or

```
InputStream is1 = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/classes/ANALYSIS_template.xlsx"));
```

**Edit :**

Use this when you are accessing the file from a servlet container

```
InputStream is1 = ServletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/classes/ANALYSIS_template.xlsx") ;
```

Comment: Sorry neither of these seem to be working

Comment: Thanks but I'm still stuck.  Perhaps after lunch divine inspiration.  Everything you've suggested is what the internet says is the right way to go.  I wonder if something else sketchy is going on...

Comment: This was helpful but in the end it wasn't the right code.  I still voted you up for assistance

Comment: Thanks for up-voting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the java File object, you can try this:

```
String path = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("language/file.xml").getPath();
File f = new File(path);
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this potentially an issue with the relative path to the file vs the absolute path to the file? 
Can you attempt to use FileInputStream and use the absolute path? If that works then you may just have to tinker with the relative path?

Comment: Thats a good idea.  I'll try it out tomorrow morning.